# how to retrieve the audio file from database

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, c#-4.0

```
stream = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("E:\sogam.wav")

str = "INSERT INTO reg (Name,ContentType,Data)VALUES(@Name,@ContentType,@Data)"
Try
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, dbcon)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = "hope1"
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContentType", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = "audio"
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", OleDbType.Binary, 30).Value = stream
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("inserted")
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("not working")
End Try
```

---

well above is my code which inserted the .wav file in the database(whereas Data is binary datatype)
can anyone say how to retrieve the audio file

Comment: SELECT query that will return `Data` column?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't store the audio in the database. I would store the path to the file that reside on a server. Sometime, database space cost more money than harddrive space.

Comment: i retrieved,but i cant play it. (code for conversion - system.io.file.writeallbytes("E:\trie.wav",dr.getValue(2)) computer.audio.play("E:\trie.wav",AudioPlayMode.Background) )

Answer (score 0):

Very simple:

```
SELECT
    Data
FROM reg r
WHERE 
    r.ContentType = 'audio
    and r.Name = 'hope1'
```

Comment: i retrieved,but i cant play it. (code for conversion - system.io.file.writeallbytes("E:\trie.wav",dr.getValue(2)) computer.audio.play("E:\trie.wav",AudioPlayMode.Background)  )